# How can I handle "ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence"

Tags: python, exception

```
def build_word_affect(self):
    affect_list = []
    affect_dict = dict()
    affect_frequencies = Counter()
    lexicon_keys = self.lexicon.keys()
    for word in self.words:
        if word in lexicon_keys:
            affect_list.extend(self.lexicon[word])
            affect_dict.update({word:self.lexicon[word]})
    for word in affect_list:
        affect_frequencies[word] += 1
    sum_values = sum(affect_frequencies.values())
    affect_percent = dict()
    for key in affect_frequencies.keys():
        affect_percent.update({key:float(affect_frequencies[key])/float(sum_values)})
    self.affect_list = affect_list
    self.affect_dict = affect_dict
    self.raw_emotion_scores = dict(affect_frequencies)
    self.affect_frequencies = affect_percent
```

Using the above code, I tried to get max_value of the frequencies

```
emo_dict = self.affect_frequencies
max_value = max(emo_dict.values())
```

But the error occurred "ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence', 'occurred at index 36')" I found that the error occurred because there is sometimes text that I input doesn't have any word in the lexicon_keys in the code --> `if word in lexicon_keys:`
So I tried hard to make some exception like `if word not in lexicon_keys:` but it doesn't work... Please help me to fix this code guys.. Thank you in advance.

FYI. There are 26,000 different words in the lexicon_keys.

Comment: Why do you have `**for`?

Comment: That was typo. I just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use Try...except code

```
try:
    if word in lexicon_keys:
            affect_list.extend(self.lexicon[word])
            affect_dict.update({word:self.lexicon[word]})
except ValueError as ve:
    print(ve)
    #code if Value error occurs
except Exception as e:  
    print ("NameError: str(e)")
    #code if anyother error occurs
else:
    #code if no errors
```

Comment: The error was "ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence', 'occurred at index 36')"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have everything consistent with your usage, since you failed to supply self-sufficient code.  You need to check whether any member of `words` is also in `lexicon_keys`.  There are two simple ways to do that.

One is a simple application of the `any` function:

```
if any(word in lexicon_keys for word in self.words):
```

The other is a simple application of set intersection:

```
if set(self.words).intersection(set(lexicon_keys)):
```